# Validation for Nested JSON object

Tags: json, api, go, beego

```
{
 "firstname": "sathish",
 "lastname": "kumar",
 "city": {
    "id": 12,
    "name": "coimbatore"
 },
 "referrals": [
    {
        "name": "vignesh",
        "mobile": "1234567890"
    },
    {
        "name": "melvin",
        "mobile": "1234567890"
    }
 ]
}
```

Above is my JSON request for creating new profile. I need to do validation for above JSON using Beego validation package

```
type ProfileForm struct {
 Firstname string `json:"firstname" valid:"Required"`
 Lastname  string `json:"lastname" valid:"Required"`
 City      struct {
    ID   int    `json:"id" valid:"Required"`
    Name string `json:"name" valid:"Required"`
 } `json:"city"`
 Referrals []struct {
    Name   string `json:"name" valid:"Required"`
    Mobile string `json:"mobile" valid:"Required"`
 } `json:"referrals"`
}
```

I need to know the how can write the validation for JSON request using struct in Beego. Let me know are the any package or tutorial for this kind of requirement.

In official beego documentation I didn't see anything matches my requirement.

Comment: This will not match since `Referrals` is an array of objects not an object

Comment: @Himanshu I have updated my struct. Let me know if you have any idea.

Comment: your question is not clear what you want actually 'a verification if your struct is matching or not' because that I have already mentioned

Comment: @Himanshu My question is how can I validate the above json data using beego?